# Haskell remove 0 element after scanl

Tags: haskell

I am trying to use `scanl()` to keep a running sum of a list. I am currently getting a `0` in my list although I want to remove it. I have tried to use `take 1` to take everything from index `1` although it is not working.

Input: `[3,5,1,6,2,8,1]`

**Expected** output: `[3,8,9,15,17,25,26]`

**Current** output: `[0,3,8,9,15,17,25,26]`

```hs
ongoingSum :: [Int] -> [Int]
ongoingSum = scanl (+) 0
ongoingSum = take 1
```

When running the above code I get the following error:

```hs
 Multiple declarations of ‘ongoingSum’
    Declared at: hello.hs:17:1
                 hello.hs:18:1
   |
18 | ongoingSum = drop 1
```

How can I get my desired output?

Comment: you were close, just use `drop` rather than `take`

Comment: @RobinZigmond Still get the same error.

Comment: Joseph's answer below is the right way to do this, but just a comment on the error message you are getting - it's telling you exactly what is wrong.  You're declaring `ongoingSum` twice.  The compiler can't tell if you are trying to define onGoingSum to be a thing that does a scanl or a thing that does a take (though in this case the compiler could probably infer that one of them has the wrong type signature, but it hits the duplication first and stops).

Answer (score 4):

If you want to keep using `scanl` for some reason, then the right way to use `drop 1` is to compose that with your original function with the `.` operator, like this:

```
ongoingSum :: [Int] -> [Int]
ongoingSum = drop 1 . scanl (+) 0
```

However, there's a better solution: just use `scanl1` instead:

```
ongoingSum :: [Int] -> [Int]
ongoingSum = scanl1 (+)
```

Unlike, e.g., `foldl1`, `scanl1` is not partial and won't fail on empty lists, so there's no downside, and the upside is that instead of having an extra element you're going to throw away, it's just never generated at all.